# Merchant listings structured data issues detected in google search Console saying Missing field 'image'

Tags: wordpress, missing-data, google-search-console, google-merchant-center

HI I found this issue in google search console where it says that Merchant listings structured data issues detected in google search Console saying Missing field 'image'. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

I see product images are show on site images are not missing but google says it is missing. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: This relates to hidden structured data on your pages that define your product. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.